Is there any function, which could solve the linear superposition of two gaussian noise with different mean and stddev like Fourier transform?
After superimposing two sine functions with different frequencies, through Fourier transform, it is easy to know which sine functions with different frequencies are superimposed to form the superimposed function. So, here is my question, if I superimpose two 2D Gaussian noises with different means and standard deviations, is there any method to identify these two Gaussian noises just like Fourier transform?

Short answer is no. You can even make a plausible Gaussian noise distribution by adding ~6 uniformly distributed random numbers together. You can't unmix an omelette. Any half decent statistics textbook will give you the answer to how they combine.

show us some pictures. give us data.

ok let me change the stupid question, for a pure gaussian noise image, could a function tell me the mean and stddev of it?

Changing a question from impossible to trivial is quite a change.

I think OP is talking about mixture distributions, not the distribution of a sum. But only OP can clarify that point.

OP, a web search for "mixture model" "expectation-maximization algorithm" with find some relevant resources.

data please. either real data, or representative synthetic data. we are getting nowhere by exchanging prose.

I assume you mean you add two noise realizations together. There is no way  to disambiguate them. Adding two normally-distributed noise realizations yields a new normally-distributed noise realization whose mean is the sum of the original two means, and whose standard deviation is the square root of the sum of the squares of the original two standard deviations.

OP ought to clarify. I think they mean gaussian mixture models.

so how about if I mix two different kind of noise? like one gaussian and one poisson?

@fgg1991 The more noise realizations you add together (of any type) the more it looks Gaussian. Also, Poisson looks gaussian if the mean is large enough. But if you have a model, say you know the noise is composed of a Poisson component and a Gaussian component, then you can try to fit the sum model to your data. The challenge is to distinguish the case where the Poisson distribution has a high mean from the case where the Poisson distribution has a very small contribution (low amplitude), since in both cases it would look more or less the same.
